# Testing ActiveSupport::Notifications with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

Does anybody know how you can spec an active support notification? The following doesn't seem to work. It detects the default rails framework notifications but not my custom one.

```
it 'sends a "product.search" notification to any subscribers listening'
  ActiveSupport::Notifications.should_receive(:instrument).with("product.search", :search => search) 
  get :search, ...
end
```

If I change the spec to check the outcome of the subscriber's code (e.g. record count change when creating a DB record) it passes. That confirms that it is working ok. But, it seems wrong to spec what the subscriber does here, I just want to spec that the notification is being sent. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here is the controller code that I'm trying to spec:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("product.search", :search => 'test')
```

Comment: is your tag `rpsec` a typo? [Probably intended `rspec`?]

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and wrote the following rspec helper method below:

```
  def notification_payload_for(notification)
    payload = nil
    subscription = ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe notification do |name, start, finish, id, _payload|
      payload = _payload
    end

    yield

    ActiveSupport::Notifications.unsubscribe(subscription)

    return payload
  end
```

This way, I can use it as follows:

```
 it "should raise the my_notification_name notification" do
    payload = notification_payload_for('my_notification_name') do
      # do stuff that should raise the proper notification
    end

    # test to see that the payload has the correct info
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to achieve the test using a regular `:get` action, something should interfere somehow and only `start_processing` and `process_action` notifications are triggered. I guess it has been disabled for performance sake.

But this successfully works:

```
it 'sends a "product.search" notification to any subscribers listening'
  ActiveSupport::Notifications.should_receive(:instrument).with("product.search", :search => "test")
  controller.index
end
```